# Forcing HTTP in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I am trying to force my site to redirect from https to http, most of the tutorials out there do the opposite (force http to https), the few one's that I have come across haven't worked for me so far.

This is what my .htaccess file looks like right now

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: Any of the answers below will work. Just replace one of them with your own and refresh your cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to force HTTPs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: I got a response of "example.com redirected you too many times"

Answer (score 1):

Use this to force to http:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I got a response of "example.com redirected you too many times"

Comment: Do you use HSTS, or proxy server (cloud) ?

Comment: Have you replaced your first 3 lines with these lines, and cleared the cache?

Answer (score 1):

You do exactly the opposite, namely if it comes from HTTP

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

redirect to HTTPS

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Remove these two lines and replace with the following.

---

First, you should not check for the port, but for [`%{HTTPS}`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), which is more reliable, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

next redirect to HTTP (note the missing `s`)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Much better answer.

Comment: I got a response of "example.com redirected you too many times"

Comment: This could happen, when you keep the original rules in addition to the new ones. Then it will redirect from HTTPS to HTTP, the browser will request HTTP, and again will be redirected from HTTP to HTTPS, and so on.